# Can pandas implicitly determine header based on value, not row?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

I work with people who use Excel and continuously add or subtract rows unbeknownst to me. I have to scrape a document for data, and the row where the header is found changes based on moods.

My challenge is to handle these oscillating currents by detecting where the header is.

I first organized my scrape using `xlrd` and a number of conditional statements using the values in the workbook.

My initial attempt works and is long (so I will not publish it) but involves bringing in the entire sheet, and not slices:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook(fName)
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sht)

return book,sheet
```

However, it is big and I would prefer to get a more targeted selection. The header values never change, nor does when the data shows up after this row.

Do you know of a way to implicitly get the header based on a found value in the sheet using either `pandas.ExcelFile` or `pandas.read_excel`?

Here is my attempt with `pandas.ExcelFile`:

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(fName)
dataFrame = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sht,
                          parse_cols=21, merge_cells=noMerge, 
                          header=header)

return dataFrame
```

I cannot get the code to work unless I give the call the correct header value, which is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010670/how-to-process-excel-file-headers-using-pandas-python) seems to present a similar problem without addressing the concern of finding the headers implicitly.

Comment: why don't you loop and parse the first rows of the sheet until you find the line where the header is? It will give you the number of rows to pass to `skip_rows` and you will have pandas parsing you table as usual.

Comment: Loop and parse using what? That's what my xlrd code does, but I'm unclear how this woud look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same loop through ExcelFile objects:

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(fName)
sheet = xlsx.sheet_by_name(sht)
# apply the same algorithm you wrote against xlrd here
# ... results in having header_row = something, 0 based
dataFrame = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sht,
                      parse_cols=21, merge_cells=noMerge, 
                      skip_rows=header_row)
```